# using context in navigationOptions in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to use my created Context in the Component.navigationOptions, but I can't access it from outside the component

I have tried the "props.navigation.setParams/props.navigation.getParams, but they always freeze up my screen and they don't do any good

```
const AddNoteScreen = props => {
    const {addNote} = useContext(Context);
    const [title, newTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, newDescription] = useState('');

    props.navigation.setParams(addNote);


    return <>
        <Spacer/>
        <Input label='Note Title' value={title} onChangeText={newTitle} />
        <Spacer/>
        <Spacer/>
        <Input label='Note Detail' value={description} onChangeText={newDescription} multiline={true} numberOfLines={9} />
    </>
}

AddNoteScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
        title: "Add your note",
        headerTintColor: navigation.getParam('HeaderTintColor', '#fff'),
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(254, 56, 56)',
            borderBottomEndRadius : 18,
            borderBottomStartRadius : 18,
        },
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
             navigation.getParam(addNote(newTitle, newDescription))}>
                <Feather style={styles.plus} name="plus" size={25}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
    }
};
```

I expected to be able to use the context in the navigationOptions like that, but like I said, some weird things happen and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `addNote()` inside the static navOptions, you should call it like this: `navigation.state.params.addNote()` and leave the state of AddNoteScreen outside of the navOptions.

```
const AddNoteScreen = props => {
  const { addNote } = useContext(Context);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const callNoteFromNav = () => {
    addNote(newTitle, newDescription);
  };

  props.navigation.setParams(callNoteFromNav);

  return (
    <>
      <Spacer />
      <Input label="Note Title" value={title} onChangeText={setTitle} />
      <Spacer />
      <Spacer />
      <Input
        label="Note Detail"
        value={description}
        onChangeText={setDescription}
        multiline={true}
        numberOfLines={9}
      />
    </>
  );
};

AddNoteScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    title: 'Add your note',
    headerTintColor: navigation.getParam('HeaderTintColor', '#fff'),
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(254, 56, 56)',
      borderBottomEndRadius: 18,
      borderBottomStartRadius: 18
    },
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.state.params.callNoteFromNav()}
      >
        <Feather style={styles.plus} name="plus" size={25} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  };
};
```

You shouldn't try to access state inside navOptions, because it's static. However this will be a feature on the future release. I can advise you to check out [React Navigation Next](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/getting-started.html). The people of React Navigation replaced the static options with a more React kind of way of configuring the [header](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/headers.html).

Happy coding!

Comment: There is one problem though, Jurrian. When I add 'props.navigation.setParams(callNoteFromNav)' , somehow I can't click anything on the screen. I can't even write anything in the input component, the keyboard doesn't open. Any idea why this is happening? Even the back button doesn't work :/

Comment: Okay, I resolved that error by using 'useEffect' . It's giving me an error : 'navigation.state.params.callNoteFromNav is not a function. (In 'navigation.state.params.callNoteFromNav()', 'navigation.state.params.callNoteFromNav' is undefined)

Comment: Could you make a reproducible sandbox, then I'l take a closer look. https://codesandbox.io/